# How can I make a Windows Media Player control transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, windows-media-player

In a C# Winforms application with a transparent form, how can I have a Windows Media Player control with a specific opacity or transparency setting so that it 'blends' into the background.

I have set the uiMode to none, yet am not sure on how to make the content transparent.

Comment: You don't need to do any specific work. Just put the player control on the form and set the `Opacity` of form to a desired value like `50%`. The form, including the player and playing video will be shown with the opacity.

Comment: @MickyD You can simply test it.

Comment: Have you done any research? There is a tonne of information, this MSDN question is probably the [best](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/12d4c726-70c8-4ac5-8105-c7f0739ed6b9/c-transparency-rendering-videos-windowsforms?forum=winforms)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Learnt something new today. Thanks Reza :)

Comment: @MickyD You are welcome :)

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are looking for.